# How can I prevent the DRC in KiCAD from checking my silkscreen layers?

Tags: kicad, silkscreen, drc

I am currently working on a PCB with a lot of components which are very close to one another. For this PCB I do not want to manufacture the silkscreen layers and I do not want the DRC to check for silkscreen errors. Currently I get a lot of "overlap in silkscreen" or "Silkscreen clipped by soldermask" errors. How can I prevent the check on them?

- KiCAD-version: 5.99 (nightly build)
- OS: macOS X (11.5.2 Big Sur)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the violation severity in your "Board Setup" dialog.  Change it to "Ignore" for the silkscreen items

[image: Violation severities]

Comment: You are awesome =) I was halfway there....found board setup, but missed the violation severity option. Thank you! Upvoted and accepted.